# Unable to create read only user-- postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4, I want to make a user with permanent read only access on public schema.
I have tried many different ways to get this but using

```
REVOKE ALL on schema public to user1; 
GRANT SELECT on all tables in schema PUBLIC to user1;
```

doesn't make any sense for me, user `user1` is not able to change any table but is still able to create new tables in public schema.

Comment: Did you `commit;`?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly revoke the create privilege? `revoke create on schema public from user1`. Btw: your example `revoke` is invalid and won't run because it's `revoke ... from ...` not `revoke .. to ...`

Comment: Had you used 'commit;' statement after used of GRANT Statement.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how `REVOKE` works.

You can't `REVOKE` a right that was never `GRANT`ed. It doesn't create a deny ACL (a negative right), it removes a granted right if it exist. You didn't `GRANT` rights to `user1` on the schema; instead that user inherited them from the `public` role everyone's a member of. So you can't revoke it.

You want to revoke the right given to `public`, then grant it to roles who should have read/write. quick and dirty example:

```
CREATE ROLE read_write_user;
GRANT read_write_user TO user2;
GRANT read_write_user TO user3;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO read_write_user;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO user1;
```